# Can motorcycle (SV1000) battery lead fuse (10A) blow due to engine heat?

Tags: motorcycle

I recently put in place battery leads to charge my SV1000's battery without removing the seat. I have a suspicion, that the heat from the engine and exhaust (being close to the seat) is repeatedly blowing the fuse on the lead close to battery terminals. Is that a possibility? The leads have the safety cap on when the bike is not being charged, so little chance of shorting, what ese could it be? Otherwise the battery and motorcycle are in great shape, no signs of battery/electric trouble.

Comment: so, there is no current when this fuse supposedly blows--I detach the trickle charger from the leads, cover the leads with the protective cap, then go for a ride; when I return, and try to put the trickle charger back on, the fuse close the battery terminals is most likely blown.

Comment: Sometimes my reading comprehension isn't turned on (10A fuse rating in your title). My bad as I deleted the previous comment.  If  charging amperage of the charger is greater than fuse rating then the fuse may simply blow from higher charging current. Trickle chargers can be left connected 24/7/365 tend to limit current to less than a few amps to avoid overcharging. Are you using a 10A+ charger? This can blow the fuse. Heat from the engine wouldn't melt the fuse element. Are the charging leads directly connected to the battery?